# Batch file needs to be executed every minute from another master batch file

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch which calls internally a SSIS package (.dtsx location is written).
I want this batch file to be executed for every minute.
I can't do this using task scheduler as I have restricted permission to create a task.

Code inside the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO You are about to execute the TestPackage SSIS package
PAUSE
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "U:\C_Drive\Downloads\MyPackage\MyPackage\Package.dtsx"
PAUSE
```

Here Package.dtsx pulls the data from MYSQL Server and inserts the data to SQL Server database. Need this insertion to be done every minute.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a `timeout` command.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO You are about to execute the TestPackage SSIS package
PAUSE
:loop
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "U:\C_Drive\Downloads\MyPackage\MyPackage\Package.dtsx"
timeout 60
goto loop
```

Answer (score 1):

To call it from a master batch file. Simply call it every 60 seconds:

**master.cmd**

```
:begin
call mybat.cmd
timeout 60 /nobreak>nul & goto begin
```